# Radio input and submit pass value

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

Im trying to make a radio button form where the chosen option, "123, 456" value is passed to the "data-offer-id" part of my submit button.  I think this needs to be javascript but I don't know how to do this.  Please help if you can!.  Thanks in advance

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="data-offer-id" value="123"> 123<br>
  <input type="radio" name="data-offer-id" value="456"> 456<br>
 </form> 


<button class="btn btn-success btn-large"
                    data-dismiss="learnmodal"
                    data-cleeng-trigger
                    data-action="checkout"
                    data-locale="en_US"
                    data-display-type="overlay"
                    data-offer-id="***Need Value to dynamically populate here****"
                   data-completed-callback="cleengCallbackHandler(result)">    
<span style="color: #ffffff">$9.95 / Month
</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be handled when the radio button is clicked so that by the time the submit button is pressed, the value is already there.

```js
// Get reference to the submit button
var sub = document.querySelector("button.btn-success");

// Get a reference to both radio buttons as an array
var radBtns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='data-offer-id']"));


// Loop over the buttons
radBtns.forEach(function(btn){
  // Set each button to have a click event handler
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Set the radio button's value as the id of the submit button
    sub.setAttribute("data-offer-id", btn.value);
    
    // Just for testing:
    console.clear();
    console.log(sub);
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="data-offer-id" value="123"> 123<br>
  <input type="radio" name="data-offer-id" value="456"> 456<br>
 </form> 


<button class="btn btn-success btn-large"
                    data-dismiss="learnmodal"
                    data-cleeng-trigger
                    data-action="checkout"
                    data-locale="en_US"
                    data-display-type="overlay"
                    data-offer-id=""
                   data-completed-callback="cleengCallbackHandler(result)">    
<span style="color: #ffffff">$9.95 / Month
</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your quick response.  Unfortunately I had to change my question little to make this work.  I'm willing to paypal a few dollars if I can get this to work..Thanks again

Comment: @RobbieMiranda Answer updated to reflect your edited HTML. It really doesn't change the solution. Only the references to the elements is different.

Comment: Trying now.  Thanks

Comment: Using your updated code, I cannot get the button to fire.  If I manually add the value into the button code, it will fire.  Does the javascript need to be in the header or the same section of code with the button?  Again thanks

Comment: @RobbieMiranda all of that JavaScript should be in a script tag that is inserted in the document just before the close of the body element. As you can see from running my code it does work.

Comment: I see that, still not working for me.      <script> or     <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @RobbieMiranda Just script. Are you getting any errors in your developers console? Or, are you seeing the messages that my script is designed to show?

Comment: Sorry Scott, No luck.  http://bmxtraining.com/cleeng/01_Protect_your_content/purchase.php

Comment: @RobbieMiranda please answer my last questions. Are you getting errors in your console?

Comment: Sorry Scott, I am looking at the console in Chrome now but I'm not an expert in this.

Comment: @RobbieMiranda what does the console show when you click either one of the radio buttons?

Comment: @RobbieMiranda I have tested the page you linked to and it is working perfectly. If you open the developer console and click either of the radio buttons, you will see the button element logged and it will have the correct `data-offer-id`.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm still not getting the pop up like my demo link under the test link. You gave me something to work with and I appreciate that. Send me your PayPal and I'll send you a couple bucks. Thanks so much

Comment: @RobbieMiranda Your question has nothing to do with pop ups. You never asked about pop ups. That's a completely different issue. Also, here at Stack Overflow, we don't accept payment for our help. Just up vote the answers that were helpful to you and mark one as "the" answer if it answered the question you asked (like mine did).

Comment: Understood Scott. You have been a great help. In my example button code, when the data-offer-id is true with the I'd, the button will trigger a pop up. The code you helped me with does not work as expected although your coding does seem to function. Maybe it's deeper in the other functions not working along side yor code.

Comment: @RobbieMiranda Again, my code doesn't cause a pop up because I did not code it to do that. This is because you did not ask about pop ups. You asked how to get the `data-offer-id` attribute of the button to be set to the value of the clicked radio button. That's what my code does. You should mark my answer as "the" answer and then ask a new question.

Comment: Yes I will give you all the credit for this.  Unfortunately, my problem still exist.  When the data-offer-id is set with a value, the button triggers a popup.  Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.  You have helped me greatly.

Comment: @RobbieMiranda Can't stress this enough, your current problem is not the question that you posted. You should post an entirely new question about the behavior you are looking for now

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="offer-id" value="123">123<br>
<input type="radio" name="offer-id" value="456">456<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.querySelector('input[name="offer-id"]:checked').value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I want to try this but need to convert to this button code...

Comment: Thanks Im trying it but having a few problems.